# How to make a main switch toggle between two sockets (or bulbs)

Tags: switches, ac, mains, socket

Is it possible to simply (without relay) make a main switch toggle between two sockets or bulbs such that both of them are never ON or OFF at the same time?

I need to control two 12 and 9 volt DC adaptors connected to same device. Is there such a switch that I can buy from a hardware store? If yes, what is it called?

Comment: Do you mean that one is always on and when toggling back and forth, there is no dead-time? If so then you need to look for "make before break" switch tech.

Comment: @Andyaka No, dead time up to few seconds is not a problem, it is to control air flow speed by a fan

Comment: Sure these switches exists. But there will no defined off-time between switching. Even if there is, surely your DC adaptors will have capacitance in them, so they will run for some time after turning off the power. And it will take some time after power-up before adapter voltage output will rise. These are parameters you can't control. EDIT: Aha, X-Y problem. You think the only way to control fan speed is by switching mains between two power supplies. There should be far better options for that, with single power supply, and no dangerous mains wiring.

Comment: @Justme Thats a good point, then I should try to mechanically hack the socket or solution to add some sort of a rocker switches to the dc lines

Comment: What exactly is a "main switch"?

Comment: Sounds like you want a single pole double throw (SPDT) switch.  If you want a normal home light switch type switch it may be called "Three way", and is the type of switch that is often used in pairs at the top and bottom of a stairway.

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes exactly. You should use the answers section instead of commenting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this question right, you're trying to switch the supply voltage for the DC fan with a switch. I've posted two possible options. The first uses a DPDT switch to switch in either the 9V or 12V supply to the fan (shown as a resistor here). The second uses a SPDT switch, but loses any isolation the two DC adapters may have.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmO5Uf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you instead need to stick with switching the AC connections, you can buy a three-way switch from any hardware store. This switch is similar to the SPDT circuit shown above. It switches a hot line between two other poles, in your case the 9V and 12V adapter, shown as R1 and R2 below. If you need an 'off' switch as well, you can add another standard switch in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYHwSS.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this at least 3 ways:

1. Keep both AC active but the load drawing only from the higher DC voltage using DC diode OR connection power diodes. (Common Cathode to load) (no manual operation or switch needed)
2. use a SPDT switch with the Pole to the AC source and Throw contacts to either load.
3. switch the DC Pole from the load and dual Throw contacts to either DC source.